# Highstocks - Current Price Indicators - label shows wrong price

Tags: highcharts

On the following chart: https://jsfiddle.net/fx4bnhzm/1/ with the following rangeSelector.buttons:

```
  buttons: [{
    type: 'hour',
    count: 8,
    text: '1s',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['second', [1]]]
    }        
  }, {
    type: 'day',
    count: 1,
    text: '1min',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['minute', [1]]]
    }        
  }, {
    type: 'day',
    count: 3,
    text: '5min',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['minute', [5]]]
    }        
  }, {
    type: 'day',
    count: 7,
    text: '15min',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['minute', [15]]]
    }        
  }, {
    type: 'day',
    count: 14,
    text: '1h',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['hour', [1]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'day',
    count: 30,
    text: '4h',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['hour', [4]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: '1D',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['day', [1]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 2,
    text: '1W',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['week', [1]]]
    }
  }, {
    type: 'all',
    text: '1M',
    dataGrouping: {
      forced: true,
      units: [['month', [1]]]
    }
  }]
```

when I change type chart to *Line chart*, and turn on *Current Price Indicators* the current price line is correct but the label shows the wrong point

[image]

Is it a bug in Highcharts / Highstocks or is it something wrong in the data?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug, I will report it and create a ticket.

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18528) ticket that you can follow.